# How to interpret this execution plan (IN vs EXISTS)?

Tags: optimization, postgresql, deferred-execution

It looks like from the execution plan the IN version is faster than EXISTS version

I'm thinking that EXISTS query is faster, for it **eagerly checks** the conditions.  The IN query though it looks intuitive, I feel that it seems it resolves the final conditions' result very late; that is, from inside out, I perceived that IN are slower because the next condition **need to wait** for the result of its inner conditions.

Though from the look of the execution plans below, the IN is faster; it has lower cost.

Part of me is wanting to use the IN version, it looks easy and intuitive for the next maintainer, and the execution plan below seems to indicate that it is faster than EXISTS.  But another part of me is wanting to use the EXISTS, because I just feel it is faster, but the execution plan below seems to contradict that perception.

Which of the two queries below is faster, is it the IN version or the EXISTS version?

IN version:

```
explain analyze
select ceil( 
        ( count(distinct company_rec_id)::numeric + 1 ) 
        / ((1)) )::int 
from 
parcel ord
join company c on c.company_rec_id = ord.client_rec_id

where
    (
        (((E'')) <> '' and to_tsvector(c.company) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(((E'')))))
        or ((E'')) = ''
    )

    and
    (
        (((0)) <> 0 and ord.parcel_number = ((0)))
        or ((0)) = 0
    )


    and parcel_rec_id in
    (
        select parcel_rec_id 
        from parcel_application 
        where parcel_application_rec_id in 
        (
            select parcel_application_rec_id 
            from parcel_application_shoe 
            where               
                (
                (((E'')) <> '' and to_tsvector(extract_words(shoe_description)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(((E'')))))
                or ((E'')) = ''
                )

                and 
                (
                (((E'')) <> '' and to_tsvector(extract_words(order_number)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(((E'')))))
                or ((E'')) = ''
                )


                and 
                (
                (((E'')) <> '' and to_tsvector(extract_words(style_number)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(((E'')))))
                or ((E'')) = ''
                )               
        )
    )

"Aggregate  (cost=1060.73..1060.75 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=29.028..29.028 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=880.43..1053.04 rows=3074 width=37) (actual time=13.261..16.365 rows=3074 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: ((ord.client_rec_id)::text = (c.company_rec_id)::text)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=864.79..995.14 rows=3074 width=37) (actual time=13.115..15.027 rows=3074 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: ((ord.parcel_rec_id)::text = (parcel_application.parcel_rec_id)::text)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on parcel ord  (cost=0.00..78.87 rows=3087 width=74) (actual time=0.005..0.373 rows=3087 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=826.37..826.37 rows=3074 width=37) (actual time=13.102..13.102 rows=3074 loops=1)"
"                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=795.63..826.37 rows=3074 width=37) (actual time=11.835..12.281 rows=3074 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=541.34..787.59 rows=3218 width=37) (actual time=7.076..10.286 rows=3218 loops=1)"
"                                Hash Cond: ((parcel_application.parcel_application_rec_id)::text = (parcel_application_shoe.parcel_application_rec_id)::text)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on parcel_application  (cost=0.00..122.18 rows=3218 width=74) (actual time=0.004..0.710 rows=3218 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=501.12..501.12 rows=3218 width=37) (actual time=7.061..7.061 rows=3218 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=468.94..501.12 rows=3218 width=37) (actual time=5.721..6.220 rows=3218 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on parcel_application_shoe  (cost=0.00..442.95 rows=10395 width=37) (actual time=0.004..2.318 rows=10395 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=11.95..11.95 rows=295 width=37) (actual time=0.136..0.136 rows=295 loops=1)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on company c  (cost=0.00..11.95 rows=295 width=37) (actual time=0.013..0.068 rows=295 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 29.122 ms"
```

EXISTS version:

```
explain analyze 
select ceil( 
            ( count(distinct company_rec_id)::numeric + 1 ) 
            / ((1)) )::int from 

parcel ord
join company c on c.company_rec_id = ord.client_rec_id
where

    (
        (((E'')) <> '' and to_tsvector(c.company) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(((E'')))))
        or ((E'')) = ''
    )

    and
    (
        (((0)) <> 0 and ord.parcel_number = ((0)))
        or ((0)) = 0
    )


    and exists
    (
        select * from parcel_application pa     
        where pa.parcel_rec_id = ord.parcel_rec_id

            and 
            exists
            (
                select * from parcel_application_shoe ord_item 
                where 
                    ord_item.parcel_application_rec_id = pa.parcel_application_rec_id

                    and         
                    (
                    (((E'')) <> '' and to_tsvector(extract_words(ord_item.shoe_description)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(((E'')))))
                    or ((E'')) = ''
                    )

                    and 
                    (
                    (((E'')) <> '' and to_tsvector(extract_words(ord_item.order_number)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(((E'')))))
                    or ((E'')) = ''
                    )


                    and 
                    (
                    (((E'')) <> '' and to_tsvector(extract_words(ord_item.style_number)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(((E'')))))
                    or ((E'')) = ''
                    )



            )
    )


"Aggregate  (cost=17773.13..17773.16 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=34.519..34.520 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=17636.59..17769.11 rows=1609 width=37) (actual time=17.174..20.426 rows=3074 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: ((ord.client_rec_id)::text = (c.company_rec_id)::text)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=17620.95..17731.35 rows=1609 width=37) (actual time=16.882..18.862 rows=3074 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: ((ord.parcel_rec_id)::text = (pa.parcel_rec_id)::text)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on parcel ord  (cost=0.00..78.87 rows=3087 width=74) (actual time=0.006..0.409 rows=3087 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=17601.74..17601.74 rows=1537 width=37) (actual time=16.858..16.858 rows=3074 loops=1)"
"                    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=17586.37..17601.74 rows=1537 width=37) (actual time=15.015..15.535 rows=3074 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on parcel_application pa  (cost=0.00..17582.35 rows=1609 width=37) (actual time=10.040..12.440 rows=3218 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: (alternatives: SubPlan 1 or hashed SubPlan 2)"
"                                SubPlan 1"
"                                  ->  Index Scan using fki_parcel_application_shoe__parcel_application on parcel_application_shoe ord_item  (cost=0.00..16.28 rows=3 width=0) (never executed)"
"                                        Index Cond: ((parcel_application_rec_id)::text = ($0)::text)"
"                                SubPlan 2"
"                                  ->  Seq Scan on parcel_application_shoe ord_item  (cost=0.00..442.95 rows=10395 width=37) (actual time=0.005..4.482 rows=10395 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=11.95..11.95 rows=295 width=37) (actual time=0.284..0.284 rows=295 loops=1)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on company c  (cost=0.00..11.95 rows=295 width=37) (actual time=0.010..0.155 rows=295 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 34.645 ms"
```

This is the final query I end up using, the **IN** version. I can only perceived marginal performance difference between 
IN and EXISTS versions.  I'm thinking more about the readability for the next maintainer, hence I used **IN**

```
select ord.parcel_number, ord.received_date, c.company
from parcel ord
join company c on c.company_rec_id = ord.client_rec_id

where

    (
        :_company = ''
        or
        to_tsvector(c.company) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(:_company))
    )

    and
    (
        :_fttsc_num = 0
        or ord.parcel_number = :_fttsc_num        
    )




and 
(
    (:_item = '' and :_order_num = '' and :_style_num = '')


    or

    ord.parcel_rec_id in
    (
        select parcel_rec_id 
        from parcel_application
        where parcel_application_rec_id in
            (

                select parcel_application_rec_id 
                from parcel_application_shoe 
                where 

                    (
                        :_item = ''
                        or to_tsvector(extract_words(shoe_description)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(:_item))                           
                    )

                    and 
                    (
                        :_order_num = ''
                        or to_tsvector(extract_words(order_number)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(:_order_num))                          
                    )


                    and 
                    (
                        :_style_num = '' 
                        or to_tsvector(extract_words(style_number)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(:_style_num))                    
                    )

            ) -- parcel_application_rec_id IN
    ) -- parcel_rec_id IN
)

and

-- material filter...
(
    (:_material = '')

    or

    -- implied material <> ''
    parcel_rec_id in 
    (
        select parcel_rec_id 
        from parcel_application
        where parcel_application_rec_id in
            (
                select parcel_application_rec_id
                from mlist
                where mlist_rec_id in
                    (
                        select mlist_rec_id
                        from mlist_detail 
                        join material m using(material_rec_id)
                        where to_tsvector(extract_words(m.material)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(:_material)) 
                    )
            )
    )

)
-- ...material filter

and

-- parameter filter...
(
    (:_parameter = '')

    or

    -- implied parameter <> ''
    parcel_rec_id in 
    (
        select parcel_rec_id 
        from parcel_application
        where parcel_application_rec_id in
            (
                select parcel_application_rec_id
                from mlist
                where mlist_rec_id in
                    (
                        select mlist_rec_id
                        from mlist_detail 
                        where mlist_detail_rec_id in 
                            (
                                select mlist_detail_rec_id
                                from mlist_detail_parameter 
                                join parameter p using(parameter_rec_id)
                                where to_tsvector(extract_words(p.parameter)) @@ plainto_tsquery(extract_words(:_parameter)) 
                            )
                    )
            )
    )

)
-- ...parameter filter

order by ord.received_date
```

Comment: Could you add the results of EXPLAIN ANALYZE?

Comment: @Frank Heikens: it's hard to get the Total Runtime, they always fluctuate and doesn't differ much. But the EXISTS seems faster, on running them ten times each, the EXISTS approach less than 30 ms five times; while with IN, only one time

Comment: I'm not asking for the runtime but for the executionplan. I asume you did a VACUUM ANALYZE before, just be sure the statistics are up to date.

Comment: if you care about maintainability, you should get rid of that "((0))<>0 and ... ) or ((0)) = 0" etc. rubbish. if you're building the query dynamically (which seems the only reason for it), omit irrelevant clauses.

Comment: @araqnid: it's not dynamic query, I'm using Npgsql's Paramater.AddWithValue. To get the final query(the one I posted here), I intentionally introduced typo to be able to get the actual query from pg_log, hence the obscure ((0))) = 0, (('')) = ''.  And those double parenthesis are generated by Npgsql.  Some of the search filter are optional hence **(:_item <> '' and field = :_item ) or :_item = ''**.  Though just awhile ago, I have thought that it can be short-circuited to **:_item = '' or field = :_item**. Already omitted unnecessary guard clauses

Comment: @Frank Heikens: I change it now to EXPLAIN ANALYZE. I thought ANALYZE only append the Total Runtime :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to re-examine that nested set of EXISTS() subqueries. [In the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110767/postgresql-exists-vs-left-join/3111025#3111025) it appears that using those doesn't perform as well as having a single EXISTS on an inner join.

so in general, transform something like:

```
where exists (select 1 from foo where foo.outer_id = outer.outer_id 
              and exists (select 1 from bar where bar.foo_id = foo.foo_id))
```

into

```
where exists (select 1 from foo join bar using (foo_id)
              where foo.outer_id = outer.outer_id)
```